# Ex 2.2.9 Jiri Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose ($x_n$) is a sequence, x $\in \mathbb{R}\;$ and $x_n \ne x \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Suppose the limit

$$ L = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\lvert x_{n+1} - x\rvert}{\lvert x_{n} - x\rvert}$$

exists and $L \lt 1. \;$ Show that $(x_n)$ converges to $x$.

**My proof:**

Since $L = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\lvert x_{n+1} - x\rvert}{\lvert x_{n} - x\rvert} \lt 1 \;, \exists M_0 \in \mathbb{N} \; $ such that  $$\frac{\lvert x_{n+1} - x\rvert}{\lvert x_{n} - x\rvert} \lt 1 \qquad \forall n \ge M_0$$

$$ \implies \lvert x_{n+1} - x\rvert \lt \lvert x_{n} - x\rvert = \frac{\lvert x_{n} - x\rvert}{\lvert x_{n-1} - x\rvert} .\frac{\lvert x_{n-1} - x\rvert}{\lvert x_{n-2} - x\rvert} ....\frac{\lvert x_{M_{0}+1} - x\rvert}{\lvert x_{M_0} - x\rvert} . \lvert x_{M_0} - x\rvert \qquad \forall n \ge M_0 $$

My reasoning is since each term is less than one, then the inequality can be bounded by a sequence of the form $p^n$ where $0 \lt p \lt 1$. Then,

$$0 \lt \lvert x_{n+1} - x\rvert \lt p^n \lvert x_{M_0} - x\rvert$$

By the squeeze theorem, the middle sequences converges to zero and hence $(x_n) \to x$

Is this proof correct? If yes, is there a way to make it cleaner?

Comment: To fix your proof, I would start by fixing the $p$ before the $n$ and also in the last inequality is $p^{n-M_0}$ instead of $p^n$

Comment: By fixing $p$ you mean to define it in the beginning?

Comment: Yes exactly. You can take for example $p = (1+L) / 2$

Comment: Much appreciated!